# ProxyPass not working alongside ProxyPassMatch

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, http, httpd

So at the moment I have a virtual host configured on my Oracle HTTP Server instance with a ProxyPass as such:

```
ProxyPass ^/test/home/ https://example.com/
ProxyPassMatch ^/test/home/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1
ProxyPassReverse ^/test/home/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1
```

When I attempt to access `https://mywebsite.com/test/home/<url_from_other_server>` the request seems to be working as expected. However, when I attempt to access `https://mywebsite.com/test/home/` it is not proxying me to `https://example.com/` but rather returning a 404.

The `ProxyPassMatch` wildcard seems to be working for all suburls I attempt to access, but the regular `ProxyPass` keyword is not.

I have also attempted removing the `ProxyPass` entirely and I get the same 404 error when attempting to access /test/home/

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this strange behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit post with your full vhost ?

Comment: Hi @Bill. I've updated with the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been addressed. The correct configuration for this particular problem is the following:

```
ProxyPass /test/home(.*)$ https://example.com/$1
ProxyPassReverse /test/home(.*)$ https://example.com/$1
```

Removing the slash and adding the wildcard has enabled us to proxy anything following `/test/home`.

Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not quite correct. `*` means "zero or more occurrences", so `https://mywebsite.com/test/home/` is matched by it.
Change `(.*)` to `(.+)`, which means "one or more occurrences". Then your ProxyPassMatch should not match that URL anymore.

Or just remove the ProxyPassMatch line completely, it is pretty useless, the urls are handled like it by the ProxyPass line automatically.

```
ProxyPass /test/home/ https://example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /test/home/ https://example.com/
```

Comment: Hi Gerald. I've attempted that solution but it's simply going straight to a 404 now whenever accessing /test/home or any other sub-url instead of only the /test/home not working. Do you have any idea why this may be?

Comment: Check the server logs, it should show where the request ends up

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Gerald. On the access_log logfile I can see the request going through and returning a 404 for the /test/home and a 403 (which is expected, the server-to-proxy is not yet accepting our requests) for /test/home/page1.